# Excel VBA, using variables with VLOOKUp

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to add a `VLOOKUP` to a column to enter data from one sheet to another. The size of the table array on the look up sheet will vary so I want add a variable to formula.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sheets("Page1_5").Select

Dim CountryRow As Long
Cells(5, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
CountryRow = ActiveCell.Row
Sheets("Results").Select
Range("B2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Page1_5!$A$5:$F$" & CountryRow & ",6,FALSE)"
```

Any assistance would be gratefully received

Comment: Why don't you just convert the range to a table and then use the column header named ranges? These will adjust automatically without the need for VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick to a method and go with it - in the beginning you are using `Cells(5, 1).Select`, later you are using `Range("B2").Select` and at last inside the `VLookup` you have both, `RC[-1]` and `$A$5:$F$" & CountryRow`.

Also, there is no need to use `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveCell`, but instead you could use fully qualified worksheets and ranges.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestVlookup()

Dim CountryRow As Long

With Sheets("Page1_5")
    CountryRow = .Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
End With

With Sheets("Results")
    Range("B2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Page1_5!$A$5:$F$" & CountryRow & ",6,FALSE)"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Thomas Gaston have you tested the code ? is it working as you intended ?

Comment: Thanks. Worked a treat :)